# Find the range of $\Lambda(f)=2f(x+1)$ on $L^2[0,\infty)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Find the range of $\Lambda(f)=2f(x+1)$ on $L^2[0,\infty)$

I think the range is isometric to $L^2[1,\infty]$. The isometry being $\Lambda(f) \to 2f\chi_{[1,\infty]}$

So $\Lambda$ is not injective so the map could be not well defined but no matter the choice of $g$ s.t $\Lambda(f)=\Lambda(g)$ we get $2f\chi_{[1,\infty]}=2g\chi_{[1,\infty]}$. Thus the map is well defined. It is injective as $\Lambda(f)=0$ implies $f=0$ on $[1,\infty)$. Is is also surjective as $f \in L^2[1,\infty)$ implies $f/2\chi_{[1,\infty]} \in L^1[0,\infty)$. Thus the range is isometric to $L^2[1,\infty]$. A nice corollary of this is that $\Lambda$ is not compact.

Is all of this correct?

Comment: What is the target space of $\Lambda$?

Comment: @ArcticChar the problem does not specify but i assume $L^2[0,\infty)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to find the exact range of the operator  instead of saying that it is isometric to some space. Actually this operator is surjective! Let $g \in L^{2}([0,\infty)$ and define $f(x) =0$ for $x <1$, $f(x)=\frac {g(x-1)} 2$ for $x \geq 1$. The $g \in L^{2}([0,\infty)$  and $\Lambda f=g$.